# Image in comments?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there a way to insert images in comments on someone else's post? I wanted to show a snap of a screen resulted by following the their answer and to seek some more clarification on it.

Suppose if I am viewing a question that is 2 year old and the answer on it has Worked for someone (since that is the only thing that got me closer to what I want). Somehow, it didn't worked for me and I want some more clarification on it. This for sure is neither an answer nor a new question. I can't edit the original question too, just to ensure that the meaning of the original question doesn't change and the answer become irrelevant to the original question.

Comment: You can include a link to the image. Do you mean that you want an image upload form for the comment section? Or do you mean you want to actually be able to display images in the comment section?

Comment: Yes, If that's possible. Directly viewing the image always has a better effect then to follow a link to open an image. Just like we have in the question section to directly embed our images

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to add images to comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85498/is-it-possible-to-add-images-to-comments), [How can I upload an image to use it in a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145994/how-can-i-upload-an-image-to-use-it-in-a-comment) and [Including images in comments...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227089/including-images-in-comments-is-it-fine-to-use-imgur-link-in-the-comments)

Comment: Thanks for these useful links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've got a new question instead.

Ask your question with words clarifying your confusion as opposed to an image, since images can't be searched on.  Feel encouraged to link back to the original answer to provide context.

Comment: I'm not sure I would ask another question just to say an answer didn't work for me. (That's assuming it's e.g. UI elements not being arranged properly in the screenshot, not a screenshot of code.)  Hard to say if it's worth a new question without more information.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom:  If one is asking for clarification on something they're lost on, then *by definition* it's a new question.  The real Catch-22 is that the OP may not get the warmest of receptions when writing the question, so this is where the opportunity to guide them into writing a well-formulated question presents itself.

Comment: @Makoto "*The real Catch-22...warmest of receptions...*" Yeah when I first became a member here I was reprimanded many times for this. It still occasionally happens, even though I **do** put in the effort to show how my question is different. In fact, I had a perfectly-valid question closed on me just the other day for this very reason, after I had spent hours explaining how my situation was different. Due to language barriers (I assume) I just couldn't get my point across, and my question was wrongfully (IMO) closed. It seems like many times on SO, you're damned if you do, damned if you don't